# Gwt ValueChangeHandler and Calculating dynamic total value

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I have one global value and one Label widgets.

> int total = 0;
>   
>  Label lblTotal = new Label ("" + total);

I have 100 or more TextBox Widget.

> Textbox t1 = new TextBox("0");
>   
> Textbox t2 = new TextBox("0");
>   
> Textbox t3 = new TextBox("0");
>   
> ..............

And has **ValueChangeHandler** on each TextBox.

```
    t1.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

        public void onValueChange(final ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
            calculateAndSetTotal(t1);

        }
    });
     ............. 
    // initialize handlers on other textBoxes as t1 TextBox
```

And a method to show total value.

```
    private void calculateAndSetTotal(final TextBox txtAmount) {

      // skip validations , assume all will insert integer values
      Integer amount = Integer.parseInt(txtAmount.getText().trim());
      // I have no idea how to calculate total value
      //  total = 
      lblTotal.setText(""+ total);
}
```

I don't want to do as like ....

```
total = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().trim()) +
        Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().trim()) +
        Integer.parseInt(t3.getText().trim()) +
  ........
```

Has any suggestions for my problem ?

Comment: I describe my problem as **100 or more TextBoxes** because I want to create dynamic textboxes and want to add handlers;

Comment: I want to optimize performance of my program.

Answer (score 1):

First you should put your textbox widgets in an List.
Then iterate through the list and do your calculations. Try this:

```
List<Textbox> textBox_list = new List<Textbox>();

Textbox t1 = new TextBox("0"); 
textBox_list.add(t1);

Textbox t2 = new TextBox("0"); 
textBox_list.add(t2);

Textbox t3 = new TextBox("0"); 
textBox_list.add(t3);

...

for(Iterator<Textbox> i = textBox_list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {

    total = total + Integer.parseInt(i.next().getText().trim());

}


//to get the previous value of the textbox
t1.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler(){

    @Override
    public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {

        String text = t1.getText().trim();
        //anything else you want to do

    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you sir , but Iterating may similar codes that I don't want to do . I would like to get some formula for calculating total value. Eg: If I know before value and after value of event target textBox , I think I can produce formula for calculating it. But I am still trouble I don't know how to get easily before value of eventTarget TextBox. Here is a link for another my question for get before value of eventarget textbox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347311/gwt-valuechangehandler-and-getting-before-value

Comment: If so then you need FocusHandler. When user focuses on the textbox then you will save its value. This is the only sufficient and efficient solution for your problem. I will edit my answer to see what i mean.

Comment: When I add focusHandler for each textBox, I need additional variables for each textBox. If I want to create all my textBoxes by dynamically ,I think it is dificult to save each textbox value. Am I right ?

Comment: No it is not so difficult. You should create a Hashmap which is a key value structure where you will keep all your previous text string for each textBox.

Answer (score 1):

I have given the answer for your previous question [GWT ValueChangeHandler and getting before value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347311/gwt-valuechangehandler-and-getting-before-value/21348431#21348431).

But to find some of the values on a collection of textboxes or any other widget/function, as [anvlasop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630096/anvlasop) said, you have to maintain a list or any other data structure and iterate over it, unfortunately. There is no other way around it, as far as I know.